# Where can I get the 10k common English dictionary words which Stack overflow uses in related question?

Tags: discussion, seo

Where can I get the 10k common English dictionary words which Stack overflow uses in related question?

Here in SE podcast -

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/podcast-32/

> One of our major performance optimizations for the “related questions”
>   query is removing the top 10,000 most common English dictionary words
>   (as determined by Google search) before submitting the query to the
>   SQL Server 2008 full text engine. It’s shocking how little is left of
>   most posts once you remove the top 10k English dictionary words. This
>   helps limit and narrow the returned results, which makes the query
>   dramatically faster.

Comment: It sounds as though you are looking for a [text corpus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus) but, given that you are looking for a *specific* text corpus, I am migrating this question to meta so StackExchange employees can review.